# Intuitionistic consistency of surjection from naturals to reals

Tags: topos-theory, constructive-mathematics, lo.logic

Is it consistent intuitionistically (in the sense of topos theory) for there to be a surjection from the natural numbers to the (Dedekind, let us say) real numbers? [I've managed to convince myself this happens in the effective topos, but not so convincingly as I'd like; I suspect others will be able to answer more confidently and cleanly...]

Comment: You are wrong about the effective topos. The real numbers are a quotient of a set the natural number there, but this covering set is not the image of a function $\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

Comment: Ah, I was right to be unconvinced by my self-convincing, then... :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Theorem** (Intuitionistic logic with Dependent Choice): 
For every sequence $a : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ there is $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $|x - a_n| > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

*Proof.* Define a nested sequence of closed intervals $I_0 \supseteq I_1 \supseteq I_2 \supseteq \cdots$ such that the length of $I_n$ is $(1/5)^n$, as follows. Begin with $I_0 = [0, 1]$. Suppose $I_n = [u, v]$ has been defined already. Using dependent choice we choose $I_{n+1}$ to be either $[u, (4 u + v)/ 5]$ or $[(u + 4 v)/5, v]$ so that
$$a_n > (3 u + 2 v)/5 \Rightarrow I_{n+1} = [u, (4 u + v)/ 5]$$
and
$$a_n < (2 u + 3 v)/5 \Rightarrow I_{n+1} = [(u + 4 v)/5, v].$$
(You should draw a picture of $[u,v]$ divided into five equal parts.)
Observe that the choice of $I_{n+1}$ guarantees $|y - a_n| > (1/5)^n$ for every $y \in I_{n+1}$.

There is a unique real number $x$ which is contained in all the intervals. It satisfies $|x - a_n| > (1/5)^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. QED.

**Remark:** With a bit of work we can replace Dependent Choice with Number Choice, as is typical in such situations. I will leave it as exercise. (Hint: for every pair of possible endpoints of the intervals, make the choice *before* constructing the intervals.) Also, the proof works for Dedekind as well as Cauchy reals.

**Corollary:** There is no surjection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ in any realizability topos, such as the Effective topos.

*Proof.* Dependent Choice is valid in a realizability topos. Thus every sequence of reals misses a real by the above theorem. QED.

Now the really interesting question is whether we can do without choice. I remember thinking about this with someone someplace sometime, but we never arrived at a conclusion.

By the way, it is intuitionistically consistent to assume that there is an injection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{N}$. This is validated in [Infinite Time Turing Machine (IITM) realizability](http://math.andrej.com/2011/12/06/embedding-the-baire-space-into-natural-numbers/). But since IITM realizability is a realizability topos, there is no surjection going the other way in this model.

Comment: Thanks! For what it's worth, the part of my self-convincing that doesn't go through must be the idea that subsingletons of reals surject onto reals (I was imagining this could work by sending a subset of the reals to its least upper bound (I suppose by "reals" here, I really mean something like $[0, 1]$)); had that been so, an injection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ could be reversed into a surjection from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, just to make sure: the provided link only demonstrates an injection $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \to \mathbb{N}$. I'm assuming essentially the same ideas work when the domain is switched to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, the same idea more or less, nothing shockingly different.

Comment: Also, motivated by the dependence of my original argument on the existence of suprema... is there anything interesting to say about intuitionistic surjections from N onto the MacNeille reals?

Comment: Doesn't the same argument go through? All you need to know is that a Cauchy sequence of rationals has a limit, which is the case for MacNeille reals.

Comment: Right... I guess what I'm wondering, then, is what goes wrong for injecting MacNeille reals into N in IITM realizability that doesn't go wrong for Dedekind reals. Because if the MacNeille [0, 1] does inject into N, then we will have a surjection from N to MacNeille [0, 1] by sending each natural to the supremum of its preimage. (Or did I misunderstand which notion of reals injects into N? Was that not the Dedekind reals?)

Comment: MacNeille reals are a much more complicated object than the Cauchy/Dedekind reals. Every subobject of the natural numbers object has decidable equality. I doubt the MacNeille reals do, but I would have to think about it. 

Comment: You can embed the object of truth values into MacNeille $[0, 1]$, as you can into any nontrivial complete lattice. So if MacNeille reals were a subobject of $\mathbb{N}$, then so would be the object of truth values, which would imply excluded middle. But excluded middle implies that an uncountable set does not embed into natural numbers. Therefore there is no embedding of MacNeille reals into natural numbers. I hope I got that right, it was sure hard to type it on iPad.

Comment: I like that argument! But it's not obvious to me that the unique complete lattice homomorphism from truth values into MacNeille $[0,1]$ is an embedding. For example, the regular truth values form a nontrivial complete lattice, into which truth values map via double-negation. But this is only an embedding if truth values were Boolean to begin with. So simply being a nontrivial complete lattice is not enough.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good point. I was thinking of the embedding $e : \Omega \to [0,1]$ defined by $e(p) = \sup \lbrace 1 \mid p \rbrace$. If $e(p) = e(q)$ then $p \iff 1 \in e(p) \iff 1 \in e(q) \iff q$, therefore $e$ is injective and $\Omega$ is a subobject of $[0,1]$. Am I doing something wrong? It does not matter whether $e$ preserves any lattice structure, it just needs to be an injection.

Comment: Well, that's the embedding I'm thinking of too, but it's not obvious to me that $1 \in e(q) \Rightarrow q$. After all, the (only classically injective) lattice homomorphism from $\Omega$ to $\Omega_{\neg \neg}$ is also given by $e(p) = \sup \{1 | p \}$ (as is any suplattice-with-top morphism on the domain $\Omega$).

Comment: (Also, returning to the dependent choice-based argument against a surjection from N to R, I'm not sure this argument would work when R = MacNeille reals, since it depends on the dichotomy "Either $a_n > (3u + 2v)/5$ or $a_n < (2u + 3v)/5$", which seems an example of precisely the sort of thing which isn't guaranteed for general MacNeille reals)

Comment: I don't believe that the definition "$e(p) = \sup\{1 \,|\, p \}$" works, since the MacNeille reals are only *conditionally* complete (any inhabited subset with an upper bound has a least upper bound). One could fix that by changing the definition to "$e(p) = \sup(\{0\} \cup \{1\,|\,p\})$". In any case, @Sridhar: One can prove without any form of choice that for any map from the naturals to the MacNeille reals, there is a MacNeille real which is not in the image of that map. That is to say, the MacNeille reals are constructively uncountable in a strong sense.

Answer (score 9):

It appears the answer to the original question is finally available now, a decade later, due to Andrej Bauer and James Hanson, the former of which had already provided a helpful response here ten years ago. Though we do not have such a surjection in the effective topos per se, we can use a modification of the effective topos concept to get a nontrivial topos with a surjection from the naturals to the Dedekind reals. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CBFUojXoq4.